# I want to sort the string array. I know to achieve the result in diff ways. But I want to know why this method is throwing an error

Tags: c#, string, linq, sorting

I'm getting an

> Object reference not set

exception in this Program..

Where I store `Output1[k++]` there is a problem...

**CODE**:

```
    Class stringsor
      { 
        public static string[] output1;
        public static void sortstrings(string[] input1)
          {
            int k = 0;
            foreach (var item in input1)
             {

                output1[k++] = (item.OrderBy(i => i)).ToString();
             }
```

Sorting Using Linq

```
             output1 = new string[k];

              foreach(var item in output1)
              {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
              }
           }

            public static void Main(string[] args)
             {
              string[] input1 = { "Adkad","jor","ioeuo","zkas","aka","nma"};
              sortstrings(input1);
             }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is you are not initializing output array before using it.  Since you already using LINQ you can initialize and assign output array directly like below

```
    public static void sortstrings(string[] input1)
    {
        output1 = input1.Select(word => new string(word.OrderBy(i => i).ToArray())).ToArray();

        foreach (var item in output1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
```

> I want to sort the string array.

But what you currently doing is reversing the order of characters in the output array. it is not sort the string array. is that what you expect? if you need to order the strings you can so as below

```
output1 = input1.OrderBy(word => word).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You have declared `output1`, but not initialized it.

Before you use it in `sortStrings`, try.

```
output1 = new string[input1.Length];
```